# Bootbox with DeleteView can't find url in Django

Tags: python, django, bootbox

I'm using Bootbox to delete a listing in my app but the url is not working.

Here's the script:

```
<script>
    $(".delete-file").click(function () {
            var button = $(this);
            let id = button.attr("data-id");
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?",
                function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $.ajax({
                            method: "GET",
                            url: "{% url 'delete_file' pk=id %}",
                            success: function(){
                            #success
                         }
                      });
                    }
                });
        });
</script>
```

Urls.py

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.FileDelete.as_view(), name="delete_file"),
```

Html:

```
<a data-id="{{ file.pk }}" class="delete-file">Delete</a>
```

View:

```
def index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.user = request.user
        form.save()
else:
    form = FileUploadForm
allTags = Tag.objects.all()
Tag.objects.annotate(ntag=Count('taggit_taggeditem_items')).filter(ntag=0).delete()
user = request.user
files = Uploaded.objects.filter(user=user)
context = {'form': form, 'allTags': allTags, 'files': files}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Template:

```
{% for file in files %}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="cards">
            <div class="row no-gutters border rounded  flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250">
                <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
                    <h3 class="my-1"><a href="{{ file.file.url }}">{{file.name}}</a></h3>
                    <div style="display:flex">
                        {% for tag in file.tags.all %}
                        <a href="{% url 'tagged' tag.slug %}" class="mr-1 badge badge-info">#{{ tag }}</a>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <p class="mb-auto">{{file.name}}</p>
                    <p class="mb-auto text-muted">{{file.time_uploaded}}</p>
                        <form action="{% url 'file_newdescription' pk=file.pk %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ file.additional_description }}" name="additional_description">
                        <input type="submit" id="set" class="pull-right"/>
                        </form>
                    <p class="mb-auto">{{file.additional_description}}</p>
                    <a href="{{ file.file.url }}" download>Download</a>
                     <a data-id="{{ file.pk }}" class="btn-link delete-file">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Reverse for 'delete_file' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete/(?P\d+)/$']

Comment: What is your django version

Comment: The version is 3.1.

Comment: Use the path function for url patterns `path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.FileDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_file'),` and according to your error the I'd is empty. You are missing the ID of the object.

Comment: Post the view, the template too, is 'file' in your view request context?

Comment: But I've assigned the ID to data-id and in the script I take it in variable named id. The data-id attribute is working and has the correct ID but it's still not working.

Comment: I've added the template and the View function.

Comment: The view that renders this template.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I've changed the view. A little more clarification: This view renders the page which has multiple items. I also have a DeleteView that takes you a confirmation page which I'm trying to avoid with Bootbox.